# Can the dhatu elements be considered as permanent?

Tags: abhidhamma

Can the dhatu elements (earth, water, wind and fire) be considered as permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think they ought to be considered as permanent.

Modern physics and chemistry use the word 'element' to refer to [the various types of 'atom'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element).

The word ['dhatu' is translated as 'element'](http://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/dhatu/index.html) in a different way:

> Whatever is characterized:
>
> - by hardness (thaddha-lakkkhana) is the earth or solid-element;
> - by cohesion (ābandhana) or fluidity, the water-element;
> - by heating (paripācana), the fire or heat-element;
> - by strengthening or supporting (vitthambhana), the wind or motion-element.
>
> All four are present in every material object, though in varying
>   degrees of strength. If, for instance, the earth element predominates,
>   the material object is called 'solid', etc. - For the analysis of the
>   4 elements, s. dhātu-vavatthāna.

Any compound object (for example, a tree) might have some of these characteristics: but the object (e.g. the tree) is impermanent, and (therefore) the characteristics of the object are impermanent.

Comment: I believe that both answers are correct. In the book 'Buddhism. One Teacher; Many Traditions' (The Dalai Lama & Thubten Chodron - 2014), p. 144: Six Elements Are Not The Self: '(...)  The Pali commentary on the Majjhima Nikaya (MN 140:8) explains: "Here the Buddha expounds the reducibly existent by way of the irreducibly existent. The elements are irreducibly existent, but the person is not irreducibly existent. This is meant: "That which you conceive as a person consists of six elements [the 4 elements + space + consciousness]. Ultimately there is no person here. "Person" is a mere concept.'

Comment: I don't read [MN 140](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.140.than.html) as saying that something is "permanent", and I don't read "irreducible" as meaning "permanent". I think it's talking about "properties of experience" (different views, like different filters, different ways to analyze experience). I think it's like saying that, "A (composite) painting of landscape is (is composed of, or, can be reduced to) a bunch of colors." But the painting isn't permanent: and neither are the colors IMO (because the colors, IMO, depend on the painting and on being perceived).

Comment: See also [The All](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.023.than.html).

Comment: Indeed, Chris, this short Sabba Sutta explains all.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see any thing is impermanent. What is impermanent defies description or conceptualization.

Here is more info on the subject.
http://www.buddhanet.net/cbp2_f4.htm

> All things arise due to causes and conditions. As causes and
>   conditions are impermanent and will cease one day, all things will
>   also cease correspondingly. When there is rising, there will be
>   falling; when there is existence, there will be extinction. The rising
>   and existence of things has its natural tendency towards cessation and
>   extinction. It is like a wave; it comes and goes. Thus, when one sees
>   the truth of "what this is, that is; this arising, that arises", one
>   should also see the truth of "when this is not, that is not; this
>   ceasing, that ceases". The Law of Dependent Origination pointed out
>   the possibility of ending worldly suffering. It shows the way of
>   liberation that corresponds to the Law of Cause and Effect.
>
> "When one is born, one will die.  One who admires high status will
>   fall one day."
>
> This is the natural Law of Cause and Effect. It is also an inner
>   implication of the Law of Dependent Origination. It can be called the
>   Cessation Process of the Law of Dependent Origination.

As soon as one starts discussing permanence, it is already in the field of impermanence. Intellectual understanding may suggest a path. The practice of the path can lead to the unknowable. No one who has been here has ever said anything that could describe it.

Comment: See comment above